# Concat two identical SpannableString

Tags: android, concatenation, spannablestring, spannable

I'm trying to make `SpannableString` using sort of alphabet, it looks like this:

```
public ArrayList<SpannableString> alphabet;
...
temp = new SpannableString("S0");
temp.setSpan(new SubscriptSpan(), 1, 2, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
temp.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan((float) 0.75), 1, 2, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
inAB.add(1, temp);
```

Then I do this:

```
SpannedString line = (SpannedString) TextUtils.concat(alphabet.get(1), ..., alphabet.get(1));
```

And only second one is subscripted. I know that it's because of the same `SubscriptSpan()` and `RelativeSpanSize()` instances in one string, but I don't know how to do it other way

Comment: Why not create a second instance of `SpannableString` with the same content and spans?

Comment: Because first fragment creates alphabet, second makes words from it, and there will be more than one word, so I can't just make another `SpannableString` for every encounter of this symbol. Besides, I plan to make possible complicated symbols with underlines, overlines, subscript, superscript, color maybe, so if I have to make new `SpannableString` each time, I'll need to think about another system to store symbols